# Why does jQuery.getJSON return no data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, getjson

I have this method:

```
function getUserName(guid) {
    var name = "Unbekannt";

    $.getJSON(urlCurrent, {
        "method" : "get_user_info",
        "guid" : guid,
        "auth_token" : temporaryAuthToken
    }, function(data) {
        if (data.status == 0) {
            alert(data.result[0].name);
            name = data.result[0].name;
        }
    });

    return name;
}
```

Nearly all is working: the Ajax-Request gets data and fires the callback-function, so that

```
alert(data.result[0].name);
```

shows a popup with this value: "Forename Surname"

But then at

```
return name;
```

the method returns "Unbekannt", although name should have the new value "Forename Surname".
What happened and where´s the mistake?

Thx a lot

Comment: The call to getJSON is asynchronous. So, at the `return name;` the data probably won't have arrived yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would return the promise object from the function and act on it.

```
function getUserName(guid) {
    return $.getJSON(urlCurrent, {
        "method" : "get_user_info",
        "guid" : guid,
        "auth_token" : temporaryAuthToken
    });
}

getUserName(guid).done(function(data) {
    if (data.status == 0) {
        alert(data.result[0].name);
    }
});
```

And, if you wanted to do the status check up front, .then is good for that.

```
function getUserName(guid) {
    return $.getJSON(urlCurrent, {
        "method" : "get_user_info",
        "guid" : guid,
        "auth_token" : temporaryAuthToken
    }).then(function(data){
        return $.Deferred(function(def){
            if (data.status == 0) {
                return def.resolve(data);
            }
            return def.reject(data);
        });
    });
}

getUserName(guid).done(function(data) {
    alert(data.result[0].name);
});
```

Comment: While this works, it means that you need to repeat the `.status == 0` check in every place where `getUserName` is called. It would be better if you kept that part in the `getUserName` function

Comment: @David It gives much more functionality; now you can give it a `fail` or `always` callback, combine it with other promise objects with `$.when`, or use `.then` on it (still not sure what the 1.8.0 change did to `.then` though, more research needed.)

Comment: @user1600680 That can still be done, it would just require defining your own deferred object and returning it's promise.

Comment: Thx, thats a nice solution. But how can i add the "return"-Statement? The call for the getUserName-method is inside another ajax-request, which fills a list of Posts. But there´s only a guid given so that i have to get the username with a second ajax request.

Comment: You can't add the return statement. That way of coding doesn't work with asynchronous events.

Answer (score 3):

When you return `name` it hasn’t been assigned the new value you got from the getJSON callback yet, since the ajax call is asynchronous and takes some time to complete.

You need to bring a callback function instead:

```
function getUserName(guid, callback) {
    var name = "Unbekannt";

    $.getJSON(urlCurrent, {
        "method" : "coinor.get_user_info",
        "guid" : guid,
        "auth_token" : temporaryAuthToken
    }, function(data) {
        if (data.status == 0) {
            alert(data.result[0].name);
            name = data.result[0].name;
            callback(name);
        }
    });
}

getUserName(guid, function(name) {
    alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `return name;` is performed before the ajax call has been returned.

If you want it to relate to the data that has been returned in the `$.getJSON()` call, it needs to be inside the callback function as well.

Comment: However it is also important to note that returning data from within the callback won't have any effect.

Comment: That was one of my other attempts. That didn´t work as well :(